# Despliegue de efecto con materialize

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Tengo un botón de materialize, con efecto desplegar, me despliega dos elementos de lista(español, inglés, el botón dice idiomas) al momento de hacer click no me despliega el efecto.
En la página de materialize me dice que tengo que agregar antes el CDN de jquery, sigue sin funcionar, alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para todos los componentes de Materialize se necesita inicializarlos, como lo muestra la [documentación](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html).

En el caso del componente **Select** es:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
    var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').formSelect();
  });
```

En el caso del componente **DropDown**:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
```

A mi, y por lo visto a muchos, incluso añadiendo la inicialización del componente, este no funcionaba como se mostraba en el ejemplo de la página de Materialize.

Dentro de la última versión de **Materialize CSS** disponible existen un par de componentes (versión 1.0.0), que si bien están disponibles para su uso, simplemente no funcionan, o funcionan de una manera diferente a la que se muestra en la [documentación](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html). Ya que esta última versión es Beta.

En el caso de los componentes [Select](https://materializecss.com/select.html) y [DropDown](https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) existe en la nueva versión con un pequeño problema, al desplegar no realiza el efecto esperado, que se muestra en la documentación.

Por lo mismo lo que hice fue utilizar la antigua versión de [Materialize CSS](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/) (versión 0.100.2) que si bien, dentro de ella funciona tanto el componente **select** como el **dropdown**, dentro de ella faltan muchos componentes que son bastante relevantes como por ejemplo el **DatePicker**.